# Swift 3 closure overload resolution

Tags: swift, closures, overloading, swift3, overload-resolution

I'm confused by function overload resolution with closures in Swift 3.

For example, in the code:

```
func f<T>(_ a: T) {
    print("Wide")
}

func f(_ a: (Int)->(Int)) {
    print("Narrow")
}

f({(a: Int) -> Int in return a + 1})
```

I expect `Narrow`, not `Wide`, to be printed to the console. Can anyone explain why the more specific overload gets chosen for non-closure arguments but not for closures or is this a compiler bug?

Swift 2 exhibited the expected behavior.

Comment: It's not obvious to me which behavior is "expected", but it's certainly true that Swift 2 and Swift 3 give different answers here. If this affects you in some crucial way, certainly file a bug with https://bugs.swift.org; at the very least you'll get a good answer, often in less than a day.

Comment: Yeah, "expected" merely as in "I personally didn't expect this to change."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the change in the default "escaping" behaviour for closure parameters.

If you change the specific function to:

```
func f(_ a:@escaping (Int)->Int) 
{
    print("Narrow")
}
```

it will print "Narrow" as expected (this is the same change that you probably had to make in several other places that were more obvious)