# Generic protocol Swift 4 error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics

The following code use to work for me at Swift 3.2, but with the latest release of Swift 4 I am getting an strange error I can not get to understand.

I am trying to create a generic protocol like so:

```
public protocol FactoryComponent {
  associatedtype Argument
  associatedtype Service
  static var factory: (Resolver) -> (Argument) -> Service { get }
}

public extension FactoryComponent {
    public typealias Factory = (Argument) -> Service
}
```

And using it here:

```
public extension Container {
  @discardableResult
  public func register<Component: FactoryComponent>(
    factory componentType: Component.Type
  ) -> ServiceEntry<Component.Factory> { // On this line the error shows
    return self.register(componentType.Factory.self) { resolver in
      componentType.factory(resolver)
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

**'Component' does not have a member type named 'Factory'; did you mean 'Factory'?**

And of course, the auto-fix does not help since the error is useless...

I checked out Swift 4 breaking changes and did not see anything involving generic protocols.

Can somone please help me understand what does this mean?

Comment: A *self-contained* example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a concrete class of `FactoryComponent`is missing. The `Factory` type alias can be called only by protocol's concrete classes.

1. Try create an `FactoryComponent` concrete class that implements its protocol
2. The `Argument` and `Service` still generic on your implementation and needs an concrete type. My english is very bad, but I hope I've been help you. Check the code bellow if I'm wasn't clear on my answer.

```

```
class Resolver {}

protocol FactoryComponent {
  associatedtype Argument
  associatedtype Service
  static var factory: (Resolver) -> (Argument) -> Service { get }
}

extension FactoryComponent {
  typealias Factory = (Argument) -> Service
}

class ConcreteFactoryComponent: FactoryComponent {
  static var factory: (Resolver) -> Factory {
    return foo
  }

  static func foo(_ resolver: Resolver) -> Factory {
    let factory: Factory = { argument in return "" }
    return factory
  }

  typealias Argument = String
  typealias Service = String
}

let factory: ConcreteFactoryComponent.Factory = { argument in return "" }
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is not really on the line with the return type.  The processing of generic signature resolution has changed slightly in Swift 4 due to the new default for @escaping.  The fact that the function is calling a self.register function with an identical signature as the function itself is likely the source of the issue.

From other similar instances, I would suggest looking at the signature of the Container.register.  If it happens to have an @escaping closure, then the signature of the generic function in the extension should also have one so that it is recognized as an overload.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081214/5237560

[EDIT] I just realized this change was between Swift 2 and 3.  Leaving the answer here in case it can provide some inspiration.